# Python's tqdm package license

Tags: mit, mpl, python

tqdm package seems to mention 2 types of licenses.

Here's the license for tqdm's package

```
`tqdm` is a product of collaborative work.
Unless otherwise stated, all authors (see commit logs) retain copyright
for their respective work, and release the work under the MIT licence
(text below).

Exceptions or notable authors are listed below
in reverse chronological order:

* files: *
  MPLv2.0 2015-2021 (c) Casper da Costa-Luis
  [casperdcl](https://github.com/casperdcl).
* files: tqdm/_tqdm.py
  MIT 2016 (c) [PR #96] on behalf of Google Inc.
* files: tqdm/_tqdm.py setup.py README.rst MANIFEST.in .gitignore
  MIT 2013 (c) Noam Yorav-Raphael, original author.

[PR #96]: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/pull/96


Mozilla Public Licence (MPL) v. 2.0 - Exhibit A
-----------------------------------------------

This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the
Mozilla Public License, v. 2.0.
If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this project,
You can obtain one at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.


MIT License (MIT)
-----------------

Copyright (c) 2013 noamraph

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of
this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in
the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to
use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of
the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so,
subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS
FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR
COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER
IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN
CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
```

Does this mean that the tqdm package falls under MIT, while the license file only falls under MPL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This repository contains files with 2 different licenses. Some files are under MIT license, some under MPL. They co-exist in the same package. This does not appear to be a dual-licensed situation, where you can choose which one you want.